# Using 2 foreach in the same time in asp.net mvc razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, foreach, razor-2

I want to execute 2 foreach loops at the same time. I've tried:

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.historiques) && foreach (var elt in ViewBag.statuts)
                        { .... @item  => @elt .......
}
```

But that didn't work. Is it possible?

Comment: Do you mean nested loop or execute loops asynchronously?!

Comment: `historiques` and `statuts` have the same length? If yes, you can try an `for(int i = 0; i <= ViewBag.historiques.Length; i++) { /*..*/ }`..

Comment: No they haven't the same length , historiques is a list of object and statuts is a list of string

Comment: What is your need? What do you need to do?

Comment: I want to display all property of historique and for each row I want to it affect statut

Comment: You want get status descriptions in `ViewBag.statuts`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're willing to give them type values you can use [Linq's Zip method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
@{
    var historiques = ViewBag.historiques as List<Historique>;
    var statuts = ViewBag.statuts as List<Statut>;
    var resultats = historiques.Zip(statuts, (item, elt) => new { item = item, elt = elt });
}

@foreach (var resultat in resultats)
{
    <div>@resultat.item</div>
    <div>@resultat.elt </div>
}
```

That being said, I would recommend creating a ViewModel and building what you need in that, as opposed to using a ViewBag.